# how to output two digital signal from PXI 6363 in labview

Tags: labview

I have written a labview programing, but i can't get output signal. I have created two array, and output the elements every 1ms from a line. I used the DAQmx create channel(DO digital output), DAQmx timing(sample clock), DAQmx write(digital 1D U32 1chan Nsamp).etc.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I choose port0 line0:1, use 1Chan Nsamp as picture. Where is wrong?

Comment: What is your specific question? What have you tried? Where's your code? How have you tested that your hardware is correctly set up?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nykwU.png

Comment: I don't know that why I can't get the output. When I use port0 line0:1 and two arrays to output, I can just get one output from line0. I have tried many ways but get nothing from line 1 all the time. And the output from line0 is not always right.

Comment: Where are you outputting the elements every 1 ms? All I see is 1 write operation.

Comment: The DAQmx timing(sample clock) can get this goal? I have tried using wait.vi in while loop. But it seems that there are always errors, and i can't get the output.

Comment: *Please* stop posting additional details in comments. **Edit your question.** This, combined with proper image linking, will help you tremendously. (I already fixed your original links)